# Docker container traffic through host iptables tproxy

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker, bridge

## Problem

Docker container network does not go through the host TPROXY-configured tunnel.

### Setup

I have a TPROXY-supported proxy server running on my machine (listening on 127.0.0.1:8080). I configured iptables to redirect traffic to this proxy server using `TPROXY` target as below:

```bash
ip route add local default dev lo table 100
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100

iptables -t mangle -N PROXY
# Ignore private IPs
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 192.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN

iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port 8080 --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --tproxy-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 8080 --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --tproxy-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j PROXY


iptables -t mangle -N PROXY_SELF
# Ignore private IPs
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 192.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN

iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -m mark --mark 2 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SELF -p udp -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j PROXY_SELF
```

It works as expected for locally-generated packets. However, there's a problem with Docker container packets passing through the host machine. As I didn't change any of Docker default network/iptables configuration, it uses host internet-connected device (`eth0`) as gateway to pass outgoing networks from. When I enable iptables tproxy (commands above) to redirect traffic to the proxy server, the traffic originated from inside Docker container does not reach the proxy server, and fails to access the internet. How can I resolve it?

### Debug

I used `LOG` iptables target for every chain in every table to see how packets traverse through, and to debug (or guess) what the issue is. From what I understood, for locally-generated packets as they pass through `mangle` table `OUTPUT` chain, they are marked with fwmark 1, then routed to `lo` device (instead of the default internet-connected device `eth0`) because of the `ip route`, and `ip rule` commands, and they will then received on `lo` device, which get redirected to the proxy server by `tproxy` target defined in `mangle` table's `PREROUTING` chain, and the rest of the proxying process. On the other hand, for packets sent from Docker container, they are first received on `docker0` (default Docker bridge network device), and once they are redirected by `tproxy` target, the packet *hangs* in `nat` table `INPUT` chain, which AFAIK is just before they are handed over to the proxy server process. As I don't see any log message from proxy server, I guess these packets are being dropped (?) somehow. I tested the followings as well:

- Running the proxy server bounded to `0.0.0.0`
- Enabling `net.ipv4.ip_forward` kernel option
- Letting `docker0` packets to pass through the `mangle` table `PREROUTING` chain first by just marking them with fwmark 1 (without jumping to `tproxy`), and let `ip route` to re-route them back to `lo` (similar to what happens for locally-generated packets), and then apply tproxy redirection for the associated packet that is received later on on the `lo` device. This works as expected for the *forwared* packet, but the corresponding packet that is received on `lo` device hangs right after the `mangle` table's `PREROUTING` chain and does no proceed.

But with no results...

Any help is appreciated.

As I'm new to iptables advanced networking on Linux (started completely since 3 days ago), please also let me know if there is any more information that needs to be provided.

Cheers